# Flutter: Add item below GridView

Tags: gridview, layout, flutter

I need to add an item below the GridView in Flutter. It should be visible only once a person scrolls down the grid completely.

The item should be full-width, so having it as the last item in the gridview is out of the question.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need [slivers](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/slivers) to achieve this. The idea here is to have lots of lists and scroll each one completely before starting to scroll the second one.

To use slivers you need a `CustomScrollView`, which has a property called `slivers` that, in practice, works pretty much the same as `children` works for multiple child widgets.

There is variety of sliver widgets for you to choose which one fits in your needs. If you need a Grid, you must use a `SliverGrid`. You can pass the Grid children through the `delegate` property.

As far as I'm concerned, there's no sliver widget that limits you to only one child — all of them are multiple child widget — so the last widget you mentioned must be inside a List (or whatever else you'd rather).

Seems like you need something like this:

```
Container(
  child: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      // This one is scrolled first
      SliverGrid(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          // Place your children here
        ]),
      ),
      // Then this one becomes visible and start scrolling as well
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          // Place that last widget here
        ]),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

First Create a Column add your Grid Code in First Children and than use Expanded() to display your last item.

See below code.

```
Container(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      //your grid code
      // grid code
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          child:Column(
            //your last item.
          )
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
)
```